# where to find spark.ml dataframe implements about Collaborative Filtering

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, collaborative-filtering

I am just going over spark ml tutorials ,but I did't find official documents about Collaborative Filtering.So where can I find implements about Collaborative Filtering using dataFrames?

Answer (score 0):

You can find more information about the Collaborative Filtering for latest spark 1.6.0 in below [location](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-collaborative-filtering.html).

You can also refer this [link](https://databricks-training.s3.amazonaws.com/movie-recommendation-with-mllib.html) to get more info about the same.

Comment: Thanks,but I am looking for implements in spark.ml,not in spark.milib

Answer (score 0):

There is a PR pending regarding documentation for spark.ml's collaborative filtering here: https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/10411

Unfortunately, there hasn't been much interest on spark committers' side lately despite a few pings.

Comment: I wrote a blog post on spark.ml's als [here](http://benfradet.github.io/blog/2016/02/15/Alernating-least-squares-and-collaborative-filtering-in-spark.ml)